# Can someone explain why this if else in Python is not working

Tags: python

Very new to Python and I can't get to understand why the inputs is passing through as TRUE with second condition. I was expecting to print "," instead I'm getting ".":

```
def define_punctuation(inputs):
    text = inputs.split()
    if text[len(text) - 1] != '/end' and text[0] == 'how' or text[0] == 'when' or text[0] == 'what' or text[0] == 'why':
        text = '?' 
        print(text)
    elif text[0] != 'how' or text[0] != 'when' or text[0] != 'what' or text[0] != 'why' and text[len(text) - 1] == '/end': 
        text = '.'
        print(text)
    else: 
        text = ','
        print(text)

define_punctuation('test test test')
```

Comment: You've used or condition on the second `elif` statement. text[0] is 'test' which is not equal to 'how', so it prints "."

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın yes, but I was expecting the second part of the condition text[len(text) - 1] == '/end' to turn the statement to false. I don't know why 'test' == '/end/' is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use like this

```
def define_punctuation(inputs):
    text = inputs.split()
    if (text[len(text) - 1] != '/end') and (text[0] == 'how' or text[0] == 'when' or text[0] == 'what' or text[0] == 'why'):
        text = '?' 
        print(text)
    elif (text[0] != 'how' or text[0] != 'when' or text[0] != 'what' or text[0] != 'why') and (text[len(text) - 1] == '/end'): 
        text = '.'
        print(text)
    else: 
        text = ','
        print(text)
```

As in your case you have used like this

```
    if text[0] != 'how' or text[0] != 'when' or text[0] != 'what' or text[0] != 'why' and text[len(text) - 1] == '/end':
```

Which say if any of condition goes write it will execute the statement

e.g

```
if False or False or True or False and False
```

Here this is wrong approach to write condition as it will execute when it will get True

Right approach is

```
if (False or True or False) and (False)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just learned about this :)

Comment: this is working now thanks, now I have an issue when I pass /end "hey, print this /end" the end result should be "hey, print this." but I get "hey, print this," not sure why, I added what you suggested, not sure why this throughs TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to this

```
(text[0] != 'how' or text[0] != 'when' or text[0] != 'what' or text[0] != 'why') and text[len(text) - 1] == '/end'
```

in the second (elif) statement.